# Changing auto-released object to non-auto

Tags: objective-c, xcode, memory-management, autorelease, nsautoreleasepool

Is there a way to change an autoreleased object to one that is non-autoreleased?

NSCoder's decodeObjectForKey returns an autoreleased object, which messes with a couple memory systems in my app.  How can I change its returned value to a non-autoreleased object?

I know I can run retain on it, but if I release it, it'll still remain autoreleased.  Whereas, I want to manage the memory myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set up an autorelease pool before you retrieve the autoreleased object. It will be in *that* autorelease pool. Retain the object. Now release the autorelease pool. Your object is no longer in an autorelease pool. It's retained, and it's now your responsibility to release it.